# Why does < exist to redirect to stdin

Tags: shell, pipe, stdin, io-redirection

## Question

Why do shells implement alternative means like `<<<`, `< <(command)` and `< /dev/fd/*` to redirect something to `stdin` when pipes do exist?

## Example

### The `|` way (classic pipes)

```
echo 'text' | sed 's/x/y/'
# or
cat - | sed 's/x/y/' # type text afterwards
```

### The `<<<` way

```
sed 's/x/y/' <<< 'text'
```

### The `< <(command)` way

```
sed 's/x/y/' < <(echo 'text')
# while <(command) becomes a file descriptor like
sed 's/x/y/' < /dev/fd/42
```

---

All of them return `teyt`.

Comment: It generalizes to file descriptors beyond stdin. `4<<< text 5< <(echo text2)`

Comment: I perceive `<<<` as a *"quickie"* shorthand, e.g. `bc <<< 3*4` rather than `echo 3*4 | bc`. I tend to use `program <(...)` when I have to use a program that only accepts pathnames as arguments but doesn't read `stdin`. YMMV.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "why" questions about language design are categorically off-topic: As described at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, a question should be about a specific problem you actually face. The OP does not have any bug or other practical problem they're trying to fix; this is pure curiosity.

Comment: (Also, several of your commands are not like the others: `<<<content` has your content in a string, `<file` is reading content _from a file_; obviously these things can't substitute for each other).

Comment: @MarkSetchell, note that `echo 3*4 | bc` will behave badly in a directory containing a file named `3004`.

Comment: `<<<` is shorthand for a single-line here document.

Answer (score 1):

## Everything but `program <file` is less-suited for the use case that `program <file` handles.

The other approaches discussed all do extra work that makes them slower to set up or slower to run. `<` is the only one of the mechanisms described that connects stdin **directly** to a preexisting file and avoids extra programs, FIFOs, and other moving parts.

---

#### Case One: `program <file`

Here, you're connecting `program`'s stdin **directly** to `file`.

The shell performs the following steps:

- Fork a subprocess in which to run `program`.
- Opens `file` for read.
- Uses `fdup2()` to rename the file descriptor to be FD 0.
- Close the original pre-rename descriptor.
- Use `execve()` to actually start `program`.

---

#### Case Two: `cat file | program`

Here, you're running *two* programs: `/bin/cat`, and `program`; with the input of the second connected to the output of the first.

This means that `program` can't see what the original filename was; it can't check the file's size; it can't read it out-of-order or parallelize -- it can *only* see content as it's written by `cat`.

The shell performs the following steps:

- Use `mkfifo()` to set up a pipeline
- `fork()` off a subshell to run `/bin/cat`
- Inside that subshell, use `dup2()` to make the write side of that FIFO be connected to stdout.
- Inside that subshell, close the read side of the FIFO.
- Inside that subshell, invoke `execve("/bin/cat", "cat", "file")`.
- `fork()` off a subshell to run `program`
- Inside that subshell, close the write side of the FIFO
- Inside that subshell, use `dup2()` to make the read side of that FIFO be connected to stdin.
- Inside that subshell, use `execve()` to replace the shell with `program`.

Whenever `program` henceforce wants to read from input, it's not reading from `file`; instead, it's reading from the stdout of `/bin/cat`, which has to do an extra read and write pair.

And that's a simplified case; in the real world, the shell also needs to separate the pipeline itself from the parent process.

---

#### Case Three: `program <<<content`

This is unlike `program <file` in that it isn't taking a filename at all; it's only taking specific content, which the shell writes to a *new* file.

Here, the shell does the following (except in very new versions of bash where it does something closer to case two, but without an exec on the left-hand side):

- Fork a subshell in which to run `program`
- Create a temporary file, as with `mktemp()`, opening it for write.
- Write the string `content` to that temporary file.
- Close the write handle on that file.
- Open a read-only file descriptor on that same file.
- Delete the temporary file's directory entry (the file isn't actually deleted until no more handles on it remain; this means it'll be automatically deleted when the program you're running exits).
- Use `fdup2()` to rename that descriptor to be file descriptor 0.
- Use `execve()` to actually start your `program`, consuming the subshell.

This is better in terms of performance than `echo content | file` (often), but it also makes you do the work of writing a new copy of `content`, whereas in the `<file` case you're using content that's *already written to a preexisting file*.

---

#### Case Four: `program < <(cat file)`

This is just Case 2; you're still creating a FIFO, starting a separate `/bin/cat`, etc; it has advantages when `program` is a shell function, loop, or similar (as it runs that code in the existing shell so changes to variables are intact), but it makes almost no practical difference when `program` is in fact an external executable.

Comment: @OleTange, it happens in TMPDIR, not the cwd; and this changed in bash 5.1 or so (it was a temporary file prior to that point, and is a pipe after it). And you're right about the effects: heredocs and herestrings don't work when you don't have a writable temporary directory in versions of bash prior to the 5.x with the relevant behavior change.

Comment: @OleTange, btw, if you read the answer carefully, it _does_ specify "except in very new versions of bash".

Answer (score 0):

`cmd1 | cmd2` normally runs both `cmd1` and `cmd2` in subshells. So side-effects such as parameter assignments are lost:

```bash
$ var=a
$ echo $var
a
$ echo b | read var
$ echo $var
a
$ read var <<<c
$ echo $var
c
```

```
$ i=0
$ echo $i
$ seq 2 | while read f; do i=$((i+1)); done
$ echo $i
0
$ while read f; do i=$((i+1)); done < <(seq 2)
$ echo $i
2
```

```
$ j=0
$ echo $j
0
$ echo $((++j)) | cat
1
$ echo $j
0
$ echo $((++j))
1
$ echo $j
1
```

Comment: but, perhaps interestingly, `j=0; cat<<<$((++j))` also loses the change to `j`

Comment: _grumph_. I think this is focusing on a single aspect while leaving the larger problems with the OP's equivalencies unaddressed. (But then, if you hadn't added this answer, I wouldn't have felt any need to add my own, so... I suppose it might be for the better?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tbh, generally this issue (and what I'm going to find easier to understand when I come back to the code later) is all I'm thinking about when deciding which syntax to use. I'm still confused after reading your description, why the change to `j` doesn't persist in `cat <<<$((++j))`. It sounds like you're saying the assignment happens in the subshell (which matches behaviour but feels odd)

Comment: I'd actually need to go back and read the source (or do some quick tests with strace or sysdig) to be 100% sure of that, but it's a reasonable interpretation; setting up a heredoc after the fork means you don't need to clean up after it in the parent process -- and (some) other redirections are definitely performed post-fork.